# Every finite group $H$ is a quotient of $A_n$ for some $n \geq 1$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Every finite group $H$ is a quotient of $A_n$ for some $n \geq 1$.

Can anyone help me to prove or disprove this? I do not understand the term "a quotient of $A_n$"? Does this mean  that there will be a normal subgroup $N$ such that  $A_n/N$ is isomorphic to  $H$?

Comment: Yes, it's asking you to prove or disprove that there exists a normal subgroup $N\lhd A_n$ such that $A_n/N \cong H$. What do you know about the groups $A_n$?

Comment: $A_n$ is the group of all even permutations in $S_n$@Billy

Comment: Correct. Do you know anything about its normal subgroups?

Comment: yes... I know definition and some theorems on Normal subgroups@ Billy

Comment: My question is more specific than that. What do you know about the normal subgroups *of $A_n$ in particular*? There's a well-known result about them, and I don't think you'll get very far with this question without using it.

Comment: yes I just saw a result  "Every finite group is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_n$"  I read the proof and understood. @Billy

Comment: Can you  please name the well known theorem?@Billy

Comment: The result is that $A_n$ is a simple group when $n\neq 4$. That is, if $n\neq 4$, the only normal subgroups of $A_n$ are $A_n$ itself and the trivial subgroup.

Answer (score 6):

It is a well known result that $A_n$ is simple if $n \geq 5$. That is, there are no non trivial normal subgroups: if $H \triangleleft A_n$ then $H = 0$ or $H = A_n$. Hence, if $n \geq 5$, any quotient of the form $A_n/N$ with $N \triangleleft A_n$ is either zero or isomorphic to $A_n$ itself, and in particular it has order either $0$ or $\frac{n!}{2}$. It is clear from here, thus, that not every finite group satisfies this property: if for example $G$ is a group of order $100$,

$$
\frac{5!}{2} < |G| < \frac{6!}{2}
$$

so $G$ cannot be isomorphic to a quotient of $A_n$ for some $n \geq 1$ (note that here we discard $n\leq 4$ because in that case $G$ has more elements than $A_n $).

More generally, if your group has order different from $0$ or $\frac{n!}{2}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$, it will not be isomorphic to any quotient of $A_n$ for **$n \neq 5$**. It could be, however, that your group is isomorphic to a quotient of $A_4$. The only proper non-trivial normal subgroups of $A_4$ are of order $4$, so we have the following conclusion

> Let $G$ be a group with $|G| \not \in \{0,3\} \cup \ \{\frac{n!}{2}\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Then, $G$ cannot be isomorphic to a quotient of some $A_n$, that is,

$$
G \not\simeq A_n/N 
$$

> for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $N \triangleleft A_n$.

Comment: I understood. Can I tell that any group whose order is different from n!/2 is not   a quotient of $A_n $?

Comment: @INDIAN I've added a comment on this, like you said, that condition is (almost) sufficient. To include the cases where $G$ could be a quotient of $A_4$, we can ask for $|G| \neq 3$.